# How to call Odoo server using the API

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I've defined a server action in Odoo 10. It's easy to create a button in a view to call that server action by using the server actions ID. For example, if there server action's ID was 123:

```xml
<button name="123" type="action" string="Run Action"/>
```

Is there any way to call this action via the API? I'm not sure how to do this since the server action does not have a method name. It's just an ID. I also need to able to pass context to the action. Is this possible?

Comment: By _the API_ you mean XML/JSON RPC?

Comment: Yes I mean the xml rpc API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Odoo's base module the model `ir.actions.server` is defined (base/ir/ir_actions.py). There is a method called `run` which should be callable from the XMLRPC API.

To use a context, just add it on the call as keyword parameter (kwargs) named `context`, like:

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'check_access_rights',
    ['read'], {'raise_exception': False, 'context': {'test': True}})
```

(Example was extended from the [official example 'Calling Methods'](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html))

It seems to be a bit magic, but it's done [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/api.py#L282).

Comment: But how can I call this run method with context? Doesn't the method need active_model and active_id passed in context? Otherwise you don't get access to a record within the actions code.

Comment: You can always call it with local created contexts. How does you use the API: native or with help of a python libary (like oerpeek)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "You can always call it with local created contexts"? I am calling the API from PHP scripts using [this library](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/Ripcord). Looking at the [Odoo documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html), I don't see any way to pass `context` to a method. It says each call to `execute_kw` takes an array/list of parameters passed by position, and a mapping/dict of parameters to pass by keyword (optional). It doesn't say anything about passing `context` to the method.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Wasn't sure until now, but it is possible :-)

Comment: That is amazing, thank you for finding this. But, I need to call `run` on a specific instance of a model. `execute_kw` does not accept an ID argument. I believe it runs on the model class itself. I'm still not able to figure out the correct format for calling `run` on a specific server action while also passing a context.

Comment: The method `run` is defined as `multi` so Odoo will call it extracting the IDs from args[0]. Example: `models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'ir.actions.server', 'run',
    ([1,2,3],), {'context': {'test': True}})` will run the server actions with ID 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I have learned so much here. Thank you. I now see that `active_id` and `active_model` are present in the context of the action. I see this by logging `env.context`. I see the values for `active_model = product.product` and `active_id = 7`. However, the server action does not have any value present in it's `record` parameter. It just says that `record = None`. Shouldn't the server action automatically lookup the `record` for me?

Comment: It should be [happening here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/saas-14/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py#L606), but for some reason it's not. The action is created on the `product.product` model, so I don't see why it wouldn't be setting the `record` variable. Unless the `self._context` is different than the `context` we have been talking about.

Comment: It's going to deep in detail and away from the original question. Maybe you should ask another one :-)